# Regular Expression Pattern to Match Words in All Caps That Are Followed By a colon

Tags: java, regex

I need a pattern to match words like `APPLE:` or `PEAR:`

`[A-Z][:]`  will match the `R:` but not the whole word and thus gives me a false when I try to match.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a "quantifier":

```
/[A-Z]+:/
```

Note you don't need a character class for a single character.

Answer (score 7):

You want to match one or more capital letter which means you need to use a `+`. Also your `:` doesn't need to be in a character class:

`[A-Z]+:`

Comment: +1, and 48 sec ago on your answer and 47 ago on mine. Impressive. :-)

Comment: What about "colon preceded by a word of any length starting with a capital letter"?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Depending on your definition of word: `[A-Z][a-z]*:`

Comment: That would match `A:` and `Cat:` but not `AB:`, `cat:`, `McDonald:` or `Cat5:`

Answer (score 4):

How about `\b[A-Z]+:`?  The `\b` is for checking a word boundary btw.

Comment: I have been thinking on this one, and up to the moment I don't see a case where it would make any difference. Anyway, at this hour of the night, it's better to ask: Do you have one?

Comment: I don't think it matters. But, there is one difference. If the input is `aaaAPPLE:` his won't match anything and ours will still match `APPLE:`

Comment: @PaulPRO: Ah, of course. Thanks. Well, then it might be used if there are known cases where this applies. +1

Comment: @sidyll Don't know if the op needs it, but `4PPL3:`, `P34R:`, and `A_P_P_L_E:` won't match anything in this case.  :P

Comment: @shinkou: Right, I missed a lot of cases apparently :-) But regarding your "*Don't know if the op needs it*", yes, that's the key in regex. It's important to find the balance between developing a complex expression or a simple one, based on the knowledge you have about your data.

Answer (score 1):

`\b` can be used to capture characters only in a word-boundary ie between the start and end of a word.

`[A-Z]` indicates a range of characters and specifying A-Z specifically matches the range of characters from capital A to capital Z. In other words, only upper case letters.

End the query by trying to match a semicolon and you'll find matches of a capital letter word immediately followed by a single semi-colon.

You can use the regular expression in Java like below.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class RegexExample {
  System.out.println(
    Pattern.matches("\b[A-Z]+:", "data: stuff, MIX!: of, APPLE: or, PEAR: or, PineAPPLes: yay!")
  );
}
```

I recommend finding an online playground for regular expressions. Iterating and experimenting with regexes for a project can be a fast way to learn the limitations and find ways to simplify or improve an expression.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the `+` operator to get a match to all characters in the group

try with regex:

```
[A-Z]+\:
```